# Weird Temperature Reading Fluctuations, LabVIEW

Tags: temperature, interference

[image][image]
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTBHzR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First I apologize for the crappy drawing, but I wanted to give a basic overview of what it looks like. It doesn't show my breadboard though so those unnamed ports that look like they go into the Arduino actually go into the power and ground slots on the breadboard which are then connected to the Arduino.

I have a temperature 514TC sensor that I am connecting to my Arduino MEGA and I am reading the outputs from a LabVIEW VI. My question is that I also have a voltage divider on my breadboard and it causes my temperature readings to fluctuate. The thing is though, it only fluctuates IF I read both the temperature and voltage at the same time! So if I keep everything the same and only read the temperature the outputs are fine, but if I try to read the temperature of my sensor and the voltage of the voltage divider the outputs start to fluctuate rapidly. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

EDIT: The pictures show the heart of the problem. You can see in the blue picture of temp and voltage I get fluctuations. You can see the points where I removed power from the voltage divider and gave it back power. The bottom picture has everything the same but I read temperature only and I get no fluctuations, even with the voltage divider receiving power.

Comment: add a storage cap to reduce feedthru glitches

Comment: To begin, you need to bypass all power pins with a 0.1uF capacitors, near the sensor, and near POWER pin at AtMEGA286. Always. Second, you need to understand that since the MCU has only one ADC, you cannot read two analog values simultaneously. They only can be back-to-back, and some delay might be required for the S/H unit to follow the switch.

Comment: you know about RC filters. Source has some R value, C can be added to reduce bandwidth. There must be some sample and cap hold capacitance during ADC SAR conversion to keep input constant... somewhere.. stray noise can influence sensor output, so impedance is kept low at high f glitches or RF or PSU ripple to obtain noise free readings with attention to gnd noise and Vref noise. Sample time must include internal delays to charge S/H cap

Comment: It would be useful if OP would include the actual amplitude of undesired fluctuations, relative to overall readings. Sensitivity of temperature sensor is 10mV/C, so one needs to have a pretty clean analog environment to avoid fluctuations of several degrees.

Comment: about 28 degree fluctuations

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is "normal" reading? 30C? What do you read in failing case? 2C? Or 58C? Why you are spoon-feeding us? If you need help, please always be specific with details, they give important clues in debugging process.

Comment: I'm spoon-feeding you because I don't know what details to give since I started learning about electronics about a week and a half ago. I mean that when I only read the temperature in LabVIEW I get a stable reading of room temperature, but when I read both temp and voltage on LabVIEW I get fluctuations of temp where the temp readings zig-zag over a 28F range from the normal value of room temperature. I will post a screenshot if it helps.

Comment: I added a picture if you want to see it. I'll keep plugging away at it and see if I can find a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from web ...

> The limitation of the 328p's ADC speed is not related to the clock speed or a sw driver, but it is related to the internal ADC sample and hold system (S/H).

The ADC must sample the incoming signal such it charges an internal S/H capacitor (~14pF) through an internal resistor (up to 100kohm) to the exact voltage as it is at the analog input pin.

When the S/H cap is "charged" enough, ADC disconnects the S/H cap from the analog input and does the ADC conversion of the internal capacitor's voltage.

The value of this internal S/H component (its RC constant) is too big for a fast 10bit conversion (as you cannot charge the internal S/H capacitor fast enough via the internal resistor because the resistor is large in its value).

So even when you make the fastest conversion in your code, the internal S/H capacitor is not being fully charged (it means charged up to the level of the voltage at the analog input's pin) and you do the ADC conversion with much less precision (ie. 7bit only).

- you could try two successive readings and toss the first to see the change, but that slows the sample rate.

  - if  true, then your source impedance is too high and 0.01uF cap across Vin to port will eliminate this glitch.

Comment: Is that supposed to be .1uF or .01uF?

Comment: The OP's problem is likely due to the fact that POWER voltage is HIGH, while the signal from temperature sensor is LOW, likely 10mV* 30C ~ 300mV maybe. When reading ADC back-to-back, the S/H does not have enough time to transition from one (nearly extreme) level to another and settle.

Comment: So how do I fix it Ali? With the capacitor?

Comment: I tried adding either capacitor but I get no readings when I add it. I connected it straight from the power port on the Arduino to the power column on the breadboard, is that correct?

Comment: paste link to 514 and what are R1,R2 for?

Comment: just /2 divider? 100R?

Comment: R1 and R2 are for nothing in particular, just trying to learn what is causing this because I have the same problem in the actual project I am trying to work on. In that one I have about 3 temperature sensors connected to the Arduino mega and I have the same problem of fluctuations. I was hoping that if I could understand how to fix this then I could apply it to my actual project.

Comment: do U have a scope?

Comment: ADC's prefer low Z source. RF caps provide this over the sample interval. determine source of interference , amount of current X Z =Voltage error, but keep in mind sample rate vs internal settling time assumes Z source can charge internal 14pF cap in x? us